# How to repeat a function in this case? Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I have a function that draws a line of strings and a function that draws a box of strings:

```
duplicate :: [a] -> Int -> [a] -- Duplicates a string/array
duplicate dup n = concat $ replicate n dup

printLine :: String -> Int -> IO () -- Prints a line of strings
printLine str n = putStrLn $ duplicate str n

printBox :: String -> Int -> Int -> IO () -- Prints a box of strings
printBox str width height = putStrLn $ unlines $ replicate height $ duplicate str width

main :: IO ()
main = printBox "-" 10 10 -- Will print 10x10 box of "-" string
```

I noticed that I should use `printLine` in `printBox`, because `printLine` is a part of the functionality of `printBox`.

However, I tried many times and failed miserably. How do I use `printLine` in `printBox` to achieve the same effect? Should I somehow repeat it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replicateM_` from `Control.Monad` to implement this as follows:

```
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = printBox "-" 10 10 -- Will print 10x10 box of "-" string

duplicate :: [a] -> Int -> [a] -- Duplicates a string/array
duplicate dup n = concat $ replicate n dup

printLine :: String -> Int -> IO () -- Prints a line of strings
printLine str n = putStrLn $ duplicate str n

printBox :: String -> Int -> Int -> IO () -- Prints a box of strings
printBox str width height = replicateM_ height (printLine str width)
```

Effectively the function replicates your monadic action n times and discards the results. Documentation can be found [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM_)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PNSX14730)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know about this function. I also noticed you've put `main` above and removed the `main :: IO ()` line, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Oh, that's just how the site I used for the demo had it. No other significance :)

Comment: @Israelg99, the type signature was probably omitted to save time. It should be included in the real code.

Comment: @dfeuer, should it? That's what [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) says: "By convention, we don't usually specify a type declaration for `main`". I was sure it is common.

Comment: @user3237465, I'd say LYAH is wrong about that. Many people use `-Wall`, which will warn about the missing signature.